# Can I change the userPrincipalName of my WCF service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-services, wcf

i have the next code

```
<endpoint address="http://localhost:.........svc">
                <identity>
                    <userPrincipalName value="someone@mydominio.com" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
```

my question is I can the change the value to

```
<endpoint address="http://localhost:.........svc">
                    <identity>
                        <userPrincipalName value="other_someone@mydominio.com" />
                    </identity>
                </endpoint>
```

this is posible?
or what would be the consequences of changing this USERPRINCIPALNAME?

Answer (score 0):

You can. The consequences would be it is now running as that user with that user's permissions. You'd probably also need to include the password.

There's no way for us to tell you what would happen without context of the environment/application. You could always change it back.

Comment: _"is now running as that user with that user's permissions"_ - No, it's used during authentication.  It doesn't imply _impersonation_.  `allowedImpersonationLevel` is required. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/asiatech/2009/08/27/how-to-impersonate-or-delegate-a-client-in-wcf/

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking of ASP.NET Impersonation

Comment: That's ok. Feel free to edit your answer to include more/revised info and I'll upvote :)